# No download link for Adblock Plus

Tags: apk, ads, adblock-plus

The page https://adblockplus.org/android-about from the Adblock Plus website discusses Adblock Plus for android. It clearly refers to the version that runs in the background and blocks all ads (and is not in the Play store), *not* any of the browser versions for Android that are available in the Play store.

Clicking the link on that page for ''installation instructions'' takes you to  https://adblockplus.org/en/android-install, which is an almost blank page displaying ''**Want an ad blocker for your Android smartphone or tablet?**'' and a button which redirects you to the android store (to install a broswer ad blocker).

I can't find any discussion of this online, and everyone seems to be able to download and install the correct version from the Adblock Plus website. Am I supposed to find it somewhere else? Why doesn't Adblock Plus provide it themselves?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adblock [forums](https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=54530#wrap) says

> this product is outdated (not maintained anymore), eventually use adblock browser for android

Also, see [this post](https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=150605#wrap)

> see what said an eyeo moderator:
>   "Unfortunately at the moment we have no Android developer, therefore solving real issues is kind of difficult."

That's probably why all links on the official site are dead. They haven't bothered to update the home page.

It's not available on F-droid too but alternative stores seem to have it but obviously there won't be any support.

Comment: Just in case the reader still wants to install it, APKMirror and possibly other alternative stores have it. However, readers have been warned.

Comment: Thanks. They should really update their home page (or at least add a FAQ) so it doesn't confuse and annoy people and require them to find some forum post somewhere.

Comment: @Quaternion They should probably just refer to AdAway or similar apps. A browser is definitely not a suitable replacement for a background ad blocker.

Comment: @towe I totally agree. However, they probably would rather refer to another one of their own products, even if it is less relevant.